# How to pass a backslash as an argument via Python subprocess module?

Tags: python, subprocess, command-line-arguments

I want to use Python's subprocess to call a commandline program that requires a path to be passed in as an argument. Because this is on Windows, the path includes backslashes. I have tried many options of which a few here with the program set to print out the path argument as received from subprocess:

Escaped backslashes:

```
>>> cmd = ['f:\\code\\Util.exe', '-i', 'c:\\Users\\paul\\data.xml']
>>> subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> subprocess.communicate()
('Input path: c:\\Users\\paul\\data.xml\n', '...')
```

Single backslashes, raw format:

```
>>> cmd = ['f:\\code\\Util.exe', '-i', r'c:\Users\paul\data.xml']
>>> subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> subprocess.communicate()
('Input path: c:\\Users\\paul\\data.xml\n', '...')
```

Single backslashes:

```
>>> cmd = ['f:\\code\\Util.exe', '-i', 'c:\Users\paul\data.xml']
>>> subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> subprocess.communicate()
('Input path: c:\\Users\\paul?5data.xml', '...')
```

In every case the backslashes are passed to the Windows program as double backslashes. Is there any way to pass single backslashes to the program being called?

Comment: use a `raw str` with the `r'thisisyourstring'` `r` prefix

Comment: @R Nar: uh, isn't that what I did in the second example above?

Comment: sorry, i didnt see that!

Comment: The output is *giving you single slashes*. But the output is escaped as a Python string literal. There is no problem here.

Comment: @Busturdust: I agree that it's much cleaner but it still doesn't work :)

Comment: I think Martjin hit why I was so confused

Comment: @Pawelek: your sample output is incomplete. You omitted the stderr output; you get `('Input path: c:\\Users\\paul?5data.xml', '')` at the very least.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: yes, I omitted the stderr because it is long. Thanks to everyone for respoding. You are all correct and I must be barking up the wrong tree with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting confused by the output. `Popen.communicate()` gives you a *tuple*, containing both the stdout and stderr streams. Because you get a tuple the contents of that tuple are shown via the `repr()` function. Your *string values* contain no double backslashes, but because such backslashes carry special meaning in Python string literals, they are shown in Python literal form as doubled:

```
>>> value = r'foo\bar'
>>> value
'foo\\bar'
>>> print value
foo\bar
>>> print (value,)  # tuple
('foo\\bar',)
>>> print (value,)[0]  # back to one string
foo\bar
```

In other words: there is no problem here, you are getting *single* backslashes, but Python gives you literal notation representation (for ease of debugging).

Answer (score 0):

The first form, where you double them up, is the one that should work.  Beware, however, that when Python displays a string in quotes, it will *add* escapes.  For instance, if you type `'\\'`, the interpreter with show that exact same thing.  But in actuality it is a single back-slash.  You can see this by doing `len('\\')`, or `print '\\'`.

So my question is, are you *certain* the back-slashes are being doubled, or is Python merely escaping them when displaying them?

Comment: I'm not displaying them from Python. I'm Console.Writeline()'ing them from the C# Util.exe code. So yeah, Python is passing them as literal double back slashes to the other program.

Comment: Well, the problem is *not* in the strings that you're passing to `Popen`.  Somewhere along the line, something is deciding it needs to escape those characters.

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be to use [shlex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html) to split the string and use the list in the command.

You can find an example [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) like below.

```
>>> import shlex, subprocess
>>> command_line = input()
/bin/vikings -input eggs.txt -output "spam spam.txt" -cmd "echo '$MONEY'"
>>> args = shlex.split(command_line)
>>> print(args)
['/bin/vikings', '-input', 'eggs.txt', '-output', 'spam spam.txt', '-cmd', "echo '$MONEY'"]
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(args) # Success!
```